# Is there a way for Calabash to load an app that needs to be tested onto a phone that comes from a carrier that has the app pre-installed?

Tags: android, calabash, calabash-android

For business reasons, I cannot indulge the carrier or the app, but I need to test our app on phones that already have our app pre-installed.  I have no problems running my scripts on phones that do not come pre-installed with this app, only the ones with it.  The reason I believe is possibly because of the location of where the app is installed versus the location in which Calabash installs to.  I thought if I rooted an Android phone that had our app on it that this would solve the problem, but that's not the case since the app does not appear on the phone after being rooted.  Any suggestions would be appreciated and I apologize for the question being somewhat vague as I have to protect the companies involved.  Thanks for understanding.

To add a little more detail so it makes more sense, this app I'm testing has already been released and because it's pre-loaded on this carrier's phones, I need to be able to get permission to uninstall and then reinstall the app.  Maybe it's not possible but without getting some input I won't really know.  Again, I have no problem testing on our older test phones (before the carrier began pre-loading the app) and maybe I need to just stick with testing on that for now.  The problem with this is that it limits me from being able to test on the latest OS's.  Thanks again for any input.

Comment: try to get .apk file of the app to be test from your device. @wayne

Comment: Negative, I'm not sure you're understanding the question but I appreciate any info.  I have tried to uncomment the `uninstall` method in the before hook to prevent calabash from getting an error about not having permission to do so, which is why I had also attempted to root my test device, which didn't work either.  After commenting out the `uninstall` method I received the "App could not start" error.  After investigating the resources on said error, none of them applied or worked.  It has to be a problem with how Calabash installs and uninstalls the test app so I'll try and read more docs.

Comment: As of now it is not possible.. Calabash works like client-service architecture. Calabash from your system (server) need to connect with app in your device (client.). You can read more from here: [Less Painful Article](http://blog.lesspainful.com/2012/03/07/Calabash-Android/)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to update an app on the play store or publish a newer version first of all the package name of the app should be same and then the version code should be incremented and it should be more than that of the old version published.

Comment: Sorry but you're comment has nothing to do with the question that I had asked.  Thanks for trying I guess.

Answer (score 0):

In case the preload apk cannot be uninstalled (some preload app can also be uninstalled), and you do not have the same sign key for the preload apk, the answer would probably be impossible.

If you have the sign key of the preload apk, just resign the target-app apk and test-server apk.